# ocaml using List.map iterate over list

Tags: list, ocaml

is there a way to iterate list over the list through List.map?

I know List.map takes single function and list and produce a list that the function applies to all elements. But what if i have a list of function to apply a list and produce list of the list ?

Comment: You're taking CS421 aren't you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, however as far as I understand it, you have a list of functions and a list of values. If you want to apply all functions to all elements then you can write this:

```
(* // To get one nested list (of results of all functions) for each element *)
List.map (fun element ->
  List.map (fun f -> f element) functions) inputs

(* // To get one nested list (of results for all elements) for each function *)
List.map (fun f ->
  List.map (fun element -> f element) inputs) functions
```

In case this is not what you wanted, could you try clarifying the question a little bit (perhaps some concrete example would help)?

Comment: i think you got my idea, a function takes a list of function and a list of value and apply each function to all value. The result is the result of each function for all values. Ex) [(...);(...);(...)] list of function and [1;2;3;4] list of value then result is [[true, true, false false]; [false, true, true, true]; [...]; [...]]

Comment: I thought this was an Ocaml question not an F# one? I don't think OCaml has a |> operator.

Comment: @sashang: Thanks for the correction - I wasn't sure whether OCaml has that operator (but I thought it is so useful, so it must have it too - a mistake!). The rest of the answer should be correct.

Comment: Ocaml Batteries Included provides the |> operator. Despite it not being in the standard library, it's becoming part of common usage.

Answer (score 1):

Are you allowed to use List.map2?  Because then this is simple:

```
let lista = [(fun x -> x + 1); (fun x -> x + 2); (fun x -> x + 3)];;
let listb = [1; 1; 1];;
let listc = List.map2 (fun a b -> (a b)) lista listb;;
```

The output would be [2; 3; 4]

Edit: wait, I think I read your problem wrong.  You want to get a list of lists, where each list contains a list of a function applied to the initial list?  In other words, for the lista and listb above, you'd get:

```
[[2;2;2];[3;3;3];[4;4;4]]
```

Is this correct?

Comment: I didn't know there is list.map2 but i should use multiple list.map and nested it to loop over the list but still lost

Comment: This solution only applies each function to one element, and there must be one function for each element.

Comment: Yeah, that's what my edit was about.  The problem was worded poorly and can be interpreted several different ways.  I realized that my initial interpretation is wrong, but I'm still not entirely clear what is actually being asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
let rec fmap fct_list list = match fct_list with
    [] -> //you do nothing or raise sth
    head::tail -> List.map head list :: fmap tail list;;
```

Comment: i already knew how to do this with recursive function.. but the trick is i cannot use recursive function directly but through List.map

Comment: I don't think it is possible only with List.map. Maybe you will have to use another functions with it like List.iter, or List.fold_left or fold_right,etc

Comment: @sashang, it has been two years since i did not program in Ocaml